# How to get value in this select using simple-html-dom?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<select name="size_select" class="long form-control">
<option selected="selected" value="">Please select</option>     
<option value="6 (xxs)" title="6 (XXS)">6 (XXS)</option>    
<option value="8 (xs)" title="8 (XS)">8 (XS)</option>       
<option value="10 (s)" title="10 (S)">10 (S)</option>   
<option value="12 (m)" title="12 (M)">12 (M)</option>   
<option value="14 (l)" title="14 (L)">14 (L)</option>   
<option value="16 (xl)" title="16 (XL)">16 (XL)</option>  
<option value="18 (xxl)" title="18 (XXL)">18 (XXL)</option>     
<option value="20 (xxxl)" title="20 (XXXL)">20 (XXXL)</option>
```

How to get all value in this select?

```
$element =  $html->find('#sizeDdl',0);
foreach($element as $elemen) {
    echo ($elemen->plaintext);
}
```

I try this output:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /h2/home/website/website.com/test.php on line 11

**The idea is that each individual value should be taken and recorded in SQL base. Now is a common result , not every value separately**

Comment: Where is the DOM element with id `sizeDdl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add id in select tag as
`<select name="size_select" id="sizeDdl" class="long form-control">`
then change these lines

```
$element =  $html->find('#sizeDdl',0);     
foreach($element as $elemen) {         
    echo ($elemen->plaintext);     
}
```

to these:

```
$text_array = array();
$html = "Your html";     
foreach($html->find('#sizeDdl') as $element) { 
    $options = $element->find('option'); 
    foreach($options as $element1) { 
        $text_array[] = ($element1->plaintext); 
    } 
} 
var_dump($text_array);
print_r(text_array);
```

Comment: instead of echo use push and add it to array

Comment: _Array ( [0] => Please select 6 (XXS) 8 (XS) 10 (S) 12 (M) 14 (L) 16 (XL) 18 (XXL) 20 (XXXL) ) _ return this. But how to divide any value? Is not a general result ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72058/discussion-between-imran-qamer-and-kostov-bg).

Comment: @Kostov_BG as per chat i have edited my answer to your final solution.

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
<select name="size_select" class="long form-control">
```

to this line

```
<select name="size_select" id="sizeDdl" class="long form-control">
```

as your dom element should have id attribute which u r using in javascript and missing in html.

Answer (score 1):

There is two issues with your current code.

1) You are trying to fetch an element by an id that does not exist.
2) You are iterating through a list of elements, not its children.

Either find the element by name or give it an id (`sizeDbl`) and iterate its *children* (the `options`) instead.

You could also modify the selector to select a list of the children instead of the select itself:

```
$options = $html->find('#sizeDdl option');
```

or

```
$options = $html->find('#sizeDbl')->find('option');
```

Answer (score 0):

for getting select values with simple html dom 
just try this code it will help you

```
   $element =  $html->find('#selectIDGoesHere',0)->find('option');     
        foreach($element as $elemen) {         
            echo "Display text:".($elemen->plaintext)."<br>"; 
            echo "value:".($elemen->value)."<br>";
        }
```